# creating attribute table from a raster layer in arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I want to build a raster attribute table for a raster data with floating or double precision pixel type. But when I use the "build raster attribute table" tool from data management, an error shows up mentioning that this tool does not work for floating or double precision pixel type. What should I do?

Comment: What is the precise error? By searching here on  that I suspect you will be able to find your own answer.

Comment: Attribute table exists for integer rasters only. Possible workaround is conversion of raster to integer by removing iinsignificant decimals. In case of air temperature Int (original×10) will suffice,  with DEM it is likely to be 100, etc